# What algorithm can I use for sorting this branching List in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, sorting, branch

I'm trying to create an ordered branching list of categories, so I can find any subcategories and add `"-"` at the start; and also any subcategories that category might have and add `"--"` etc.

My test class properties looks like this:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderInList { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public IList<TestCategories> Subcategories { get; set; }
```

Example:

```
Books
-Special Offers
--Fiction
-eBooks 
--Pdf
--Mobi
Maps
-United Kingdom
--Cumbria
--West Yorkshire
```

I have a default root level category with `Id: 1`, `ParentId: 1` and `OrderInList: 1`.
So the order of the above would look something like:

```
Id   | ParentId  |  OrderInList   
 2         1             1      //Books
 3         2             1      //-Special Offers
 4         3             1      //--Fiction
 5         2             2      //-eBooks
 6         5             1      //--Pdf
 7         5             2      //--Mobi
 8         1             2      //Maps
 9         8             1      //-United Kingdom
 10        9             1      //--Cumbria
 11        9             2      //--West Yorkshire
```

How can I sort a completely unordered list to look something like the above?

Comment: That's not a "branching list", that's a tree.

Comment: Can't understand what is your input and what is the output you are looking for. Do you have an unordered list you want to transform in a tree? or do you have a tree that you want to transform in a sorted list?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me delnan, I was a bit unsure of the terminology so I described it as best I could!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of sorting is called [*Topological Sorting*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). The easiest way to sort a list topologically is using a depth-first recursive search: the order in which you leave the nodes is reverse topological. If you need to know the depth of a node in a tree so that you know how many dashes to place in front of a name, you can add an `int level` variable to your depth-first recursive method.

You can borrow an implementation from [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Topological_sort) - it does not have one in C#, but the one in Java should be easy enough to translate.

Comment: Topological Sorting is not of much use for trees IMO. There are better algorithms specific for that. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @lcfseth A tree is a special case of a graph; since the OP asks for a way to sort, it's OK to call it a topological sort, although I agree that it's rarely called that when the graph is a tree.

Comment: Cheers for this! At least I have something to work from and know what I'm looking for now. Much appreciated.